# Omega vs Mind Control

Tags: yu-gi-oh

Using mind control, my opponent takes control of Omega and uses it's effect to banish itself and a card from my hand. Does Omega return to the field,if yes then when and on whose side of the field?

**PSY-Framelord Omega**

> Once per turn, during either player's Main Phase: You can banish this
>   card from the field and 1 random card from your opponent's hand,
>   face-up, until your next Standby Phase.

**Mind Control**

> Target 1 monster your opponent controls; until the End Phase, take
>   control of that target, but it cannot declare an attack or be
>   Tributed.

Answer (score 2):

When Omega is banished it is banished to the owner's side of the field (not the controllers) so when Omega does return to the field, it returns at the owner's Standby Phase and to the owner's field.

According to [Yu-Gi-Oh! Official Rulebook Ver 9.1 page 49](http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/rulebook/EN_SDSE_Rulebook.pdf) and [the wiki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Control), when the Omega and a card from your opponent's hand is banished, they're sent to your opponent's (the owner's) Banished Zone. So when it's your opponent's Standby Phase, the effect kicks-off under his/her control.

Comment: Thanks for the response Da. Effects resolve where they are activated, so in this case wouldn't 'your next standby' apply to the player activating the effect regardless of where the card ended up during it's resolution.

Comment: This 'Enemy Controller' vs 'Photon Galaxy Eyes Dragon' seems to be consistent with your answer. If your opponent controls your "Galaxy-Eyes Photon Dragon" because of "Enemy Controller" and activates its effect, then when the monsters return to the field, "Galaxy-Eyes Photon Dragon" will return directly to its original owner's side of the field. http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Galaxy-Eyes_Photon_Dragon

Comment: From your answer, I'm not clear when the cards return, the first paragraph says Omega returns during the owner's stand-by and then in the next paragraph says the effect kicks off under your opponents Standby Phase.

Answer (score 0):

The person above is absolutely incorrect. Konami specifically made this ruling clear now (since Monster Reborn is now legal). If you control your opponent's Omega and use its effect, it will banish a card and NO LONGER return on the field. 
Source: According to Yu-Gi-Oh! Official Rulebook Ver 9.3, page 52

Comment: Can you please provide some links to back up your information.